# Create new dictionary column in Pandas dataframe of all the other columns combined with their headers

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with multiple columns, whats the most pythonic way to combine them with their column headers into a new dataframe column.  For example, given red, blue, and green, how do I add colors as a column.

```
   red  blue  green colors
0    1     2     dd      {'red':1, 'blue': 2, 'green': 'dd'}    
1    2     3     ee      {'red':2, 'blue': 3, 'green': 'ee'} 
2    3     4     ff      {'red':2, 'blue': 4, 'green': 'ff'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_dict()` to create a list of dictionaries and then assign it back to `df` as a column

```
df['colors'] = df.to_dict("records")
```

[image]